# defining operators for a template class with boost::operators

Tags: c++, boost

I've got a class which looks like this:

```
template<int DIGITS, int FRACTIONS>
class decimal{

    bool operator<(const int& rhs) const;

    template<int RDIGITS, int RFRACTIONS>
    bool operator<(const decimal<RDIGITS, RFRACTIONS>& rhs) const;
}
```

I should be able to add related comparison operators for ints with

```
class decimal : boost::less_than_comparable<fixed_decimal<DIGITS, DECSIZE>, int>{ }
```

But how can I use less_than_comparable with other decimal templates?
I'd like to be able to compare decimal<10,5> with decimal<6,4>, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible due to the way C++ compilers expand templates. You'd have to define operators for each `<DIGITS, DECSIZE>`-combination. In your place, I'd take a dynamic approach and make those two parameters member variables of your class instead of template parameters.

Comment: We can't do that unfortunately, because of the way instances have to be aligned in memory.

Answer (score 0):

For operators that return a fixed type such as `bool`, you can implement the operators manually:

```
template <int N1, unsigned D1, int N2, unsigned D2>
bool operator <(fraction<N1, D1>, fraction<N2, D2>) {
    // Normalisation omitted, using floating point arithmetic
    return (static_cast<float>(N1) / D1) < (static_cast<float>(N2) / D2);
}
```

(Of course, there are much cleverer ways to do the comparison.)

But as soon as you foray into the realms of more complex arithmetic expressions such as `operator +` this can no longer be done as easily, since the return type depends on (as of yet unknown) template arguments.

You *can* do it in C++11 as follows:

```
template <int N1, unsigned D, int N2>
constexpr auto operator +(fraction<N1, D>, fraction<N2, D>)
    -> fraction<N1 + N2, D>
{
    return fraction<N1 + N2, D>();
}
```

… and to invoke:

```
fraction<1, 2> a;
fraction<3, 2> b;
auto c = a + b;
```

If you cannot use C++11, then you need to use template metafunctions instead of normal functions / overloaded operators.

Comment: As an aside, I’m not sure how these functions should best be defined: getting their arguments by value or as `const&`. Both work. Interesting question.